# Filling Input fields having credit card formatting using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was wondering if there is a way to fill the input fields having type text and have inbuilt js event to evaluate what is being entered means, when a user types in any number it evaluates and checks the type of card and also put automatic spaces in between. But while setting the value with javascript i.e. `element.value = 'xxxxxxxx';` the formatting doesn't happen and the site evaluates the card number invalid. so how to programmatically achieve this. I am working on an extension which could auto fill card details.

I have tried using `element.dispatchEvent(Keyboardevent)` but it won't work.

the website on which i am trying is made on top of angular.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. It was something like changing the value and then dispatching an event. Since I was working with angular I needed to dispatch input event. Related codes are:

```
element.value = 'anything';
//dispatching input event after setting value ( tested for angular) 
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) ;
```